# Jquery clone a div with inputs fields(and relative values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have to copy a div in which there are multiple input fields.

```
    var a = $('#divscossalina1').html();
    $('#riepilogo').html(a);
```

If i clone an input field directly,the relative value is cloned as well.
This is not happening if i clone the container div.(the fields are cloned but not the values)
Is there a way to clone all input fields with the values,simply cloning the container div?(or rather
 writing only one clone() function and not how many the fields are.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html:

```
<div id="one">
<input type="text" name="product" value="5" class="in" />
    <input type="text" name="product" value="6" class="in" />
        <input type="text" name="product" value="7" class="in" />    
 </div>
 <button id="button">Add field</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#one').clone().insertAfter("#one");
});
```

This even clones the value in them, working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwS2N/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, there is a method named "clone". you can read api: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
$('riepilogo').html($('#divscossalina1').clone());
```

and see my fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bigxiang/533zU/

Hope it works:)

Comment: Thanks i know about clone().i'm using it to clone the container div of the fields.The problem is if I clone the div the values are not cloned but only the fields.I'm trying to clone the container div whith both(fields and values).There are several(like hundreds) fileds that's why i don't wanna use clone on every field